# ArcMap ModelBuilder: problem with %name% variable when used in iteration for projection

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinate-system, modelbuilder

I have prepared a model which should project all shape files ( currently in MUTM 81)  in a folder to MUTM 84. But when I use “%Name%” in output dataset for geodatabase as “D:\Soil Test\2881\D15\Dhuduwa.gdb\%name%”  I get message

```
 “Executing (Iterate Feature Classes): IterateFeatureClasses "D:\Soil Test\2881\D15\test" # # RECURSIVE
Start Time: Mon Mar 02 16:58:01 2015
Succeeded at Mon Mar 02 16:58:01 2015 (Elapsed Time: 0.17 seconds)
Executing (Project): Project "D:\Soil Test\2881\D15\test\BUILD_PT Point.shp" "D:\Soil Test\2881\D15\Dhuduwa.gdb\BUILD_PT Point" PROJCS['MUTM84',GEOGCS['GCS_Nepal_Nagarkot',DATUM['D_Nepal_Nagarkot',SPHEROID['Everest_Adjustment_1937',6377276.345,300.8017]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Transverse_Mercator'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',500000.0],PARAMETER['False_Northing',0.0],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',84.0],PARAMETER['Scale_Factor',0.9999],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',0.0],UNIT['Meter',1.0]] # PROJCS['MUTM81',GEOGCS['GCS_Nepal_Nagarkot',DATUM['D_Nepal_Nagarkot',SPHEROID['Everest_Adjustment_1937',6377276.345,300.8017]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Transverse_Mercator'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',500000.0],PARAMETER['False_Northing',0.0],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',81.0],PARAMETER['Scale_Factor',0.9999],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',0.0],UNIT['Meter',1.0]]
Start Time: Mon Mar 02 16:58:01 2015
ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
The table name is invalid.
The table was not found. [BUILD_PT Point]
Failed to execute (Project).
Failed at Mon Mar 02 16:58:01 2015 (Elapsed Time: 0.06 seconds)

 “
```

I have 8 .shp files in that folder containing points, polylines and polygons.  What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your model fails because your input shape files have names that contain spaces. As feature class names cannot contain spaces, you need to  use add the [Calculate Value tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//004000000004000000.htm) to your model to remove spaces from your inline variable "Name" and replace them with underscores.

[image]

In the model below, the **Name** variable is precondition to the Calculate Value tool. Set expression as shown below

```
"%Name%".replace(" ","_")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake and providing a solution.